# I'm not sure my circuit analysis is correct

Tags: transistors, circuit-analysis

I'm an electrical engineering student. I analyzed a circuit, however I'm not sure I analyzed it correctly.

This is the circuit.

[image]

I'm asked to find the voltage drop between the bases of QN and QP. Base current of Q1 can be ignored.

Here is what I've done.

[image]

I don't know if it is correct. If it is though I guess it can be analyzed further.
Can anyone help?

P.S. This is NOT an assignment. I have passed this class in the past. However I want to review some things so that is the reason I posted.

Comment: If we can ignore Q1 base current we can write that \$V_{BEQ1}=R_1I_R. \$ Thus, \$I_R = \frac{V_{BEQ1}}{R_1} \$ additional \$V_{BB} = I_RR_2 + V_{BEQ1}\$. Now you should be able to find the expression for Vbb.

Comment: @G36 does the first equation stand because R1 is in parallel with the BE junction?

Comment: @kosgian90  Yes, this is true. And also because Vbe is fairly constant (0.7V) when BJT's is Turn-ON.

Comment: @kosgian90 What do you recognize in the schematic? There are subsections there that perform certain functions. The question being asked is about one of those subsections: the vbe multiplier. In simple terms, the voltage span across it will be about vbe*(1+r2/r1) in your case. Yes?

Comment: @jonk Indeed. The voltage drop across the bases of QN and QP will also be VBB. Right? Because of the parallel connection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll find a vbe-multiplier coming in two basic forms:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIAbGI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The left side is uncompensated for the Early Effect. The right side adds compensation.

(They can also come in a PNP version, with the current **I** flowing up instead of down.)

Given a current source/sink, they will set up a programmed voltage between two nodes. These structures are very often found in the final BJT amplifier stage for low-impedance loads that you show in your question, rather than using stacked diodes for the purpose, as it provides a means (with an added potentiometer, not shown) to adjust the final stage for optimal cross-over behavior (however that may be defined.)

The output BJTs in your schematic are arranged as emitter-followers. The base-emitter voltages of each are highly temperature dependent and as the collector currents are an exponential function of the applied base-emitter voltage, it may be important to have a circuit that tracks temperature changes in the output BJTs. Since the vbe-multiplier circuit relies upon its own base-emitter voltage to determine the voltage difference it creates, if it is thermally coupled to the output BTJs (one or both) then it will track thermal variations reasonably well and reduce behavior drift over operating temperature changes.

Diodes have been and are used. But their variation over temperature can be more difficult to match with the output BJTs. And, of course, you cannot add "half a diode" in order to tweak in an optimal cross-over behavior. So, the vbe-multiplier is often found in the output stage of class-AB amplifier designs.

The BJT in a vbe-multiplier also experiences the Early Effect, where the collector current is also affected by the reverse bias to its BC junction. If the vbe-multipler's voltage difference were always exactly the same (fixed) then the BC junction voltage difference would always be the same and the impact of the Early Effect would be fixed and could be compensated in the design itself and/or with a potentiometer used to calibrate it.

But the vbe-multiplier is *supposed* to vary with expected thermal variations. That's part of its function. So the Early Effect will dynamically impact the voltage difference, moving it away from the design goal of tracking changes in the output BJTs for cross-over behavior.

To imagine the effect, start with a given operating point. Suppose the BC junction experiences a reverse voltage of one volt and the cross-over behavior is "perfect." Now suppose the output BJTs get hotter (with the vbe-multiplier BJT tracking that.) Their base-emitter junction voltages (for the same operation) decline and the vbe-multiplier's output difference *also* declines with them. But this means that the reverse voltage across the BC junction of the vbe-multiplier also declines, reducing the prior Early Effect and reducing the proportion of **I** that the collector picks up (the \$\beta\$ declines.) This means that \$R_2\$'s voltage difference increases, pulling the collector voltage back upwards just a little bit until the Early Effect kicks in a little more and everything comes back into equilibrium, again. But that new equilibrium state now is with a slightly different *multiplier* than it was prior to the temperature change.

The way to "help" that situation is to place a resistor in the collector leg, which will drop some voltage based upon the collector current. If the BC junction voltage difference gets larger and attempts to increase the collector current, the new resistor will drop more voltage in response and therefore act as a negative feedback to reduce the increasing BC junction voltage. And visa versa for changes in the opposite direction. In effect, the compensation resistor in the collector leg is negative feedback against Early Effect changes and helps to keep the vbe-multiplier functioning closer to the design goals.

For the left-side vbe-multiplier, and treating the bottom node as ground for these purposes, KCL for the base node is enough:

$$\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{R_1}+\frac{V_{_\text{B}}}{R_2}+I_{_\text{B}} = \frac{V}{R_2}$$

By definition, \$I_{_\text{B}}=\frac{I_{_\text{C}}}{\beta}\$. But \$I_{_\text{C}}=I - \frac{V-V_{_\text{B}}}{R_2}\$ as it is whatever is left over after the current through \$R_2\$ is accounted.

So:

$$I_{_\text{B}}=\frac{I - \frac{V-V_{_\text{B}}}{R_2}}{\beta}$$

Substituting that into the first equation and solving for \$V\$ provides:

$$V=V_{_\text{B}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\frac{\beta}{\beta+1}\right) + I\cdot\frac{R_2}{\beta+1}$$

The first term is the vbe-multiplier part and can be simplified to \$V_{_\text{B}}\cdot\left(1+\frac{R_2}{R_1}\right)\$, for pencil and paper purposes.

The second term is the necessary drop caused, as \$\frac{I}{\beta+1}\$ is close to the base current itself, by the effect of the BJT base current 'error' flowing through \$R_2\$. The usual process of making the \$R_1\$/\$R_2\$ resistor divider *stiff* mitigates this error term. As a rule, if you size \$R_1\$ such that it has about 10% of the collector current in it, you'll find that this error term will be \$\approx 100\:\text{mV}\cdot\left(\frac{V}{V_{_\text{B}}}-1\right)\$. For the *doubler* case, that is just \$100\:\text{mV}\$. (That assumes \$\beta\ge 111\$ and the error term improves, getting smaller with higher \$\beta\$ values.)

The value of \$V_{_\text{B}}\$ is, of course, the base-emitter junction voltage and it depends upon the collector current you choose to set. For example, I might expect to see \$V_{_\text{B}}=700\:\text{mV}\$ when \$I_{_\text{C}}=4\:\text{mA}\$. And since the voltage varies proportionately with the logarithm of the collector current, a precision current source isn't really needed.

Here's an LTspice run using an idealized NPN to remove effects that weren't accounted for in the above analysis:

[image]

Upon testing, I found that at \$I_{_\text{C}}=4\:\text{mA}\$ the base-emitter voltage was closer to \$691\:\text{mV}\$. So for this run I plugged in that value, as I needed it. I also allow setting the fraction of the collector current that should appear in \$R_1\$. (I compute the vbe-multiplier value, \$M\$, accordingly, and use it in other calcs.)

The results prove out the ideas I've laid out here, pretty well!

---

Since you didn't bring up the idea of a collector compensation resistor, I'll leave its analysis to another time.

Comment: Hi jonk - I want to take this opportunity to tell you that I find it really remarkable how much energy and time you invest in such detailed answers.

Comment: @LvW Thanks. I appreciate the kind comment very much. I guess part of why is that I dislike very much qualitative hand waving. It's important to me that theory derived into circumstances makes quantitative predictions. I wish others would show evidence and therefore expect it in my own writing and of myself. If I can't prove it to me, then I've not written enough. Anyway, thanks. Your opinion means a lot.

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean - however, I think that "qualitative hand waving" also has its own value. At first, it is the precondition for all the "quantitative predictions". And it is the basis for understanding. I think, each enginer should always ask "why"? Why are we allowed to use the formula U=I * R. Does this formula say that U is the result of I ? As you know, the relation Ic=B * Ib is even more "problematic". Is it really possible that - as many people believe (!!) - a very small current could be the cause of a larger current? Qualitative question: Why should this be possible?

Comment: @LvW No question. And while, *"all particles of matter attract all other particles of matter"* is the basis for developing the necessary quantitative predictions when that idea is deduced into specific circumstances, one cannot say they ***understand*** something in a particular domain unless they can make those deductions to quantitative statements of prediction on their own. Feynman put *"what I cannot create, I do not understand"* on the upper left corner of a chalkboard, one day, for this very reason.

Comment: @LvW That said, being able to make quantitative predictions doesn't mean one understands, not in the way you suggest anyway. Feynman also is quoted, *"I think I can safely say that nobody understands quantum mechanics."* And the current state of the predictive power of the standard model is still being haggled over with regard to *meaning*, which still fails us. So, while I think it ***is*** necessary to be able to develop quantitative prediction (and precision boundaries that limit its range), it ***is not*** necessary to understand it. In all cases, though, a quantitative mindset remains.

Comment: @LvW I'll leave with one last random thought. Spice uses the Meyer capacitance model for MOSFETs. But that model cannot ever comport with the actual MOSFET behavior (as it will always result in creating and destroying charge.) And there is no possible charge function possible that can be differentiated to generate the Meyer capacitance model. And yet that's what's used. Oh, well. No idea why I bring it up, exactly. But there it is.

Comment: Jonk It took some time to grasp the content of your remarks (also the linguistic side).
Now an interesting exchange of thoughts with philosophical background has developed here.  Of course you are right that there are many areas in physics that we use and calculate with without really being able to understand them. But I am not a physicist, but only an engineer who tries to understand the phenomena in his limited electronic environment when he works with them. 
That's all. 
That is why I think it is important to always ask the question "why"? I am sure that we certainly agree on this point.

Comment: @LvW There's so many different levels swirling in my mind, when I consider answering you here about asking why. For example, you can *understand* a magnetic field as Maxwell did -- a classical view. And, given the acceptance of a magnetic field as a thing unto itself, a non-relativistic view of the universe works just fine. But is that why? No. At the next deeper level, there is no such thing. Instead, it arrives because of the speed of light. Ever notice that the electric force (N/C) divided by c results in the Tesla unit? (which it must).

Comment: @LvW And that's just with the [special theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism_and_special_relativity) applied. It gets still deeper. At what point does one decide they understand the why? And, in fact, do they really??? So I'm not sure I can answer this. We understand models at varying levels of generality and which apply over certain domains of experience. Yet we still know absolutely ***nothing*** about reality. We just like to perceive we do.

Comment: @LvW If you know that there is something called "hot" and another thing called "cold" and that matter can have mixtures of these two different things, you have a model that does explain many things. So if you hold that view, does that mean you understand ***why***? Perhaps. But then the model fails, elsewhere. And you need a more general understanding where there is nothing called "cold" anymore. But now you have energy and two emergent phenomena called temperature and entropy. But even here, these ideas also fail. So do we understand things when we know statistical thermodynamics? Nope.

Comment: @LvW One thing we humans ***are*** smart enough to do is to add and subtract numbers and compare one with another one and say, *"Yup, this magnitude is larger than that magnitude."* All we have, as engineers, is our ability to properly apply the right models given situations and come up with predictions that, when tested, pan out well enough. All we have are quantities in the end. But we do need to understand models well enough to know which to apply and when, and to be able to deduce them correctly into the situation at hand. Everything is about approximation. For *Why?* See: *Philosophy*.

Comment: (Quote): "Yet we know absolutely nothing about reality. We just like to perceive we do."  
Yes, I see it the same way. Nevertheless (or because of that), we should always ask "why"? Of course, a satisfactory answer will not always be possible. Natural laws cannot be explained - only interpreted and applied. This basic discussion was triggered by my comment on the "qualitative hand waving" you have mentioned in your 1st comment.  From this I had the impression that you consider the quantitative analyses more important than the qualitative considerations. I must have misunderstood that.